# Create light rays (like a spotlight) in SceneKit

Tags: scenekit

How would I go about creating a spotlight in SceneKit where you can actually see the cone of light, not just the light on the surface of the object it hits? Sort of like how you can see the Bat Signal's cone of light in the night sky.

It doesn't seem like SceneKit lights support this out of the box. The best I can come up with so far is adding cone geometry with material properties that sort of make it look light a light. But then how would I fade out the top part of the cone?